# Custom ROS Variant

Tags: ros, rosinstall, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I declare my own variant in rosdistro/releases/groovy.yaml to install only the packages I want?

Why would I want to do this? Not everything historically works/compiles on OSX and I would like to select which packages I install instead of the historical "ROS-Full". I am also doing work with Debian on Raspberry Pi and would like to do something similar.

Example use case:

variants:
ros-base:

- actionlib
- catkin
- common_msgs
- gencpp
- genlisp
  …
  kevin-varient
- actionlib
- catkin
- vision_opencv
- tf
  ….

If "yes," then how can I do this? Is it something like:

1. fork rosdistro
2. make changes to rosdistro/releases/groovy.yaml similar to above
3. edit /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list to point to my fork on github
4. rosinstall --catkin ~/ros "http://github.com/whatever/groovy.yaml"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49187/custom-ros-variant/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-11-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Variants are changing drastically in Groovy.

You should now be able to define a [catkin metapackage](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html#metapackage) containing only a package.xml file listing the desired dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-12-03**:
For non catkin based things variants can only be setup in the ROSDISTRO.rosdistro file, aka groovy.rosdistro file.  If you submit a custom variant as a ticket on the ros trac we can add it.  Looking forward as @joq mentions a variant will simply be a released metapackage with the common toolchain.